# ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN "Present _Address" failed because one or more objects access this column

Tags: sql-server

I have a database where I have to convert all `varchar` datatype columns to `nvarchar` type. I have been able to convert all tables except one. Before converting into `nvarchar` datatype I am dropping all constraints like foreign key, primary key, unique key, check constraints, default constraints and indexes. I also have deleted all the data before altering to `nvarchar`.

The problem is that I am getting the error

> ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN "Permanent Address" failed because one or more objects access this column.

when I am executing the drop and create table statements it is working there but while converting to `nvarchar` with `ALTER` command I am getting the error

I have the following scripts

--The actual table deifinition

```
USE [Customer]
GO
--Permanent_Address is a computed column
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer_Contact](
    [Customer_id] int NOT NULL,
    [Present_Address] [varchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [Permanent_Address]  AS ([Present_Address]))

    --Alter statement to convert from varchar to nvarchar

ALTER TABLE [Customer_Contact] ALTER COLUMN [Present Address] NVARCHAR(250) NOT NULL
ALTER TABLE [Customer_Contact] ALTER COLUMN [Permanent_Address] NVARCHAR(250) NOT NULL
```

Result-: ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN "Permanent Address" failed because one or more objects access this column.

```
--Drop and Create the table script


IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Customer_Contact]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Customer_Contact]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer_Contact](
    [Customer_id] int NOT NULL,
    [Present_Address] [Nvarchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [Permanent_Address]  AS ([Present_Address]))

--The table is created successfully with Nvarchar Datatype
```

Comment: OK, thats nice, but what is the question?

Comment: But when i run the alter commands to convert to nvarchar datatype i am getting error as ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN "Permanent Address" failed because one or more objects access this column. i need to change with alter command . Please help me

Comment: Present_address column is being reference by permanent_address. Looking at the table structure, check on the computed column specification

Comment: when i drop and recreate table then there is no error coming